# Graphs overlapping when plotting in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, pysimplegui

I've been working on this application for a while using the modsim and pysimpleGUI libraries.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1M4iodssNgmmkkjGUy_6kzuB0OVQCmcvT/view?usp=sharing

It's a pretty big hunk of code which is why I couldn't post it here.

Whenever I run the application and input values to plot a graph in the "Advanced Metrics section", some of my graphs are getting overlapped and are being plotted wrong. I'm not able to find out which variables and classes are getting mixed up resulting in graphs overlapping. It's obvious when plotting a contour plot(option 9).

I'm using the modsim library which can be installed using

```
pip install modsimpy
```

Help is appreciated. Thank you !

Comment: Maybe you could create some short example code (extracted from the larger code) that clearly demonstrates the issue? You might want to read about [creating a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). This could help a lot in attracting helpful answers.

Comment: Took a lot of installs but finally ran it. You must be talking about the PDFs you're making. I don't understand the packages you're using to make them but seems like something involved with the graph making, not the GUI portion.  Is that correct?

Comment: Yeah it's definitely with those PDFs. I don't know what's being used twice. Have you seen how the graphs overlap each other and how some graphs have unnecessary lines ? That's messing me up.